# Loading resources using ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream is not working in a particular machine

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, classloader

I have a vendor application which is deployed in Tomcat 6 on a Windows 2008 server. This application is not working in that server but when I copied the Tomcat to another machine which runs Windows 7 it is working.

When I analysis the logs that ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream is returning null in the Windows 2008 server but not in the Windows 7 machine. I checked the windows file permission the tomcat webapp folder full control has given to the user wihr runs the tomcat server. What could be the reason for this.

PS: This is a vendor application so i don't have control over the code.

Comment: Does the two machines have the same java version ?

Comment: In the Windows 2008 its 1.6.0_17 and in the Windows 7 its 1.6.0_31

Comment: Have you consider in updating the version on windows 8?

Comment: Another thing to check is the enviroment variables on both servers and see what is different. This kind of problems usually happens when there are some problem with the classpath, enviroment variables or java versions. See if you have CATALINA_HOME, JAVA_HOME, CLASSPATH defined on both servers.

Comment: Why don't you contact the vendor about the problem?

Comment: @Henry We did contact the vendor since we are using a third-party pligin they replied there will be no support

Comment: @JorgeCampos I've tested with Java 7 also checked the env variables its all fine still im getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I analysis the logs that `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` is returning `null` in the Windows 2008 server bot not in the Windows 7 machine.

That is the documented behaviour in the case when a named resource cannot be found.

> I checked the windows file permission the tomcat webapp folder full control has given to the user which runs the tomcat server. What could be the reason for this.

This is a tricky one.  Here are some things to check:

- Is the path that you are using with "getResourceAsStream" correct?
- Does the resource pathname contain non-ASCII (or special) characters than might cause Windows pathname lookup to behave strangely?
- Has the webapp been successfully redeployed (i.e. has it been stopped and started) since you last changed the WAR file?
- Have you configured Tomcat to not expand the WAR file?  If so, then the problem could be that the resource is no longer in the WAR file ... despite appearing in the (previously expanded) webapp directory.
- Is this a problem with "homoglyphs"; i.e. Unicode characters that are different but that *look* the same when you display them.
- Is it possible that a virus checker (or similar) is locking or removing the file?